# Call to undefined method App\User::hasRole()

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

I'm using `spatie/laravel-permission` to handle roles. I installed the package through composer did the migrations, and added the service provider in my `config/app.php` file, created some roles and everything fine, but when i'm going to use the blade directive `@hasanyrole` for example:

```
@hasanyrole('Profesional')

    @include('calendar.modal_appointment', ['order_details' => $order_details])

@endhasanyrole
```

It throws this error:

```
Call to undefined method App\User::hasAnyRole()
```

Answer (score 1):

Had to add `use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;` and `use HasRoles;` on my `User` model that fixed the problem